# Vertical stacking span labels in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to stack spans inside of a bootstrap div.controls. Multiple span.label's default to stack horizontally but I would like each span.label to be vertically listed instead, on it's own line per se.

This is currently how I have it displaying:

```
<div class="controls readonly-display">
    <span class="label">test</span>
    <span class="label">test 2</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gMN4f/3/

Comment: You may want to use a list instead of spans, though it seems the display style for .label should be block instead of inline-block for your purpose.

Comment: Sigh, you are right. I got stuck down the styling path and wasn't thinking about a structure change. Using a list was the right option. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list is the right option here. I got stuck down the styling path and forgot about changing the structure instead. Actually, surrounding the span elements with a unordered list actually made the vertical spacing between list items look better too.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
<div class="controls readonly-display">
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li><span class="label">test</span></li>
        <li><span class="label">test 2</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help. Sorry for the brain fart question.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that you should maybe look at using a list but if not, simply add the following to have your spans stack vertically:

```
span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gMN4f/4/